# Access 2010 / VBA / _AfterUpdate() / .Column(1)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have to work with Access 2010 as Frontend...

I have a cbo. When i choose an ArticleID from it, i would that the articletext, that belongs to it, will be shown in a txtbox below.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub artikel_nummer_soll_AfterUpdate()
artikel_bezeichnung_soll = Me!artikel_nummer_soll.Column(1)
artikel_bezeichnung_soll.Requery
End Sub
```

But the .Requery doesn't work!!?? Please help me. THX
Greetz
Vegeta_77

Comment: No. Nothing is happend, allways nothing...

Comment: Sorry. The is a msg... "... method is unknown..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i'm sorry... I have found the solution... It was my own fault :-)

artikel_bezeichnung_soll = Me!**artikel_nummer_soll**.Column(1)

THX

Vegeta_77